# Flash Builder + JSON + ac3corelib = error

Tags: json, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to receive an array using URLLoader. I included ac3corelib to my project and declared JSON library: "import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;" However, when I use "JSON.decode(e.target.data)" I get an error "Access of undefined property JSON".

Here is the code:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

private function getContacts():void {
var contacts:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

contacts.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var con:Object = JSON.decode(e.target.data);
}

contacts.load(new URLRequest("http://domain.com/cmd.php?action=contacts"));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What flash player are you targetting?

Comment: That inner function `onLoaded` isn't declared correctly. Perhaps that's what's confusing the compiler. Should be : `var onLoaded:Function = function(e:Event):void { ... }`. Or move it to the class level.

Comment: RIAstar, didn't do the trick.

Comment: Sam DeHaan, I assume, it's 11.2 (flex 4.6.0).

Comment: wvxw is probably right: native JSON was implemented since Flash Player 11. If you can target FP 11 it may be simpler to just remove the as3corelib dependency alltogether and use native `JSON.parse(x)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code

```
var con:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(e.target.data);
```

instead of

```
var con:Object = JSON.decode(e.target.data);
```

Dont forget to import below package
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

its working good for me!